# Can I request a site removal from Google and then re-index a new site on that domain?

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, googlebot

.

Basically I have replaced my site completely but upon searching Google, it returned some old pages that didn't exist anymore, so I have used the `Google index -> Remove URLs` from `Google Webmaster Tools` and deleted the few pages I found that led nowhere, and that was well and dandy. But then I noticed by changing the search words a bit, other pages that were cached and weren't accurate either. Now, unfortunately my old website was WordPress based, so there are quite a few of those cached pages that I want gone, so I went ahead and deleted the WHOLE website.

```
URL                           Status        Removal type       Requested
http://www.example.com/       Removed       Site removal       May 3, 2014
```

And it worked, my website is no longer in the search results. At all. So instead of manually requesting deletion of 50+ URLs, I got everything deleted with 1 action. Great I thought. But now I want to re-index it. and I'm not sure how to do that exactly because Webmaster Tools tells me that I have severe health issues, and if I click on that it says important pages were removed but that's accurate.

So now I went to `Crawl -> Fetch as Google` and did a request there for my `www.example.com/` and selected to submit a URL and linked pages. Now I'm waiting for my website to be indexed again.

My question is, did I do it the right way? I also have an option on `Remove URLs` to `Reinclude` the web site, but that's not what I want, because it will include the old outdated version. Did I do enough to have it re-index it? How long will it take for my site health to be back to normal, did I mess it up?

Comment: I have to admit to being afraid of the remove URL option in Google Webmaster Tools. I have only used it to remove pages that I needed immediately removed for security reasons. I have always just returned a 404 or 410 error and simply waited for the pages to drop. At the very least, I might do a 301 redirect to capture valuable users from a page that was replaced. I have no idea if removing a URL is a permanent option or not and what the ramifications are. And I am not sure too many people do either. It will be interesting to know what the experiences have been. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the Remove URLs feature before, and I think that it removes pages for 180 days. I couldn't find that information from GWT right now though.

So, your only option is to reinclude the site and manually remove the individual pages you don't want to be listed.

A better option would be to 301 redirect those to an existing page(s), so that link juice to those pages would be preserved. Still you need to reinclude the site though.

Comment: seriously? 180 days?

Comment: Sorry, remembered wrong, it is 90 days, said here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/59833?hl=en&ref_topic=1724262

Comment: okay so removing the whole site was a bad idea then, I have reincluded it and it has appeared back with the old urls and information. I will remove each individual url hand by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You did everything you can do.

Also, you have to remember, **Google is indexing, re-indexing, and deleting records from their Search Engine** all of the time at a massive rate already, but there is trillions upon trillions of sites that this needs to be done to and more links for indexing.

Just give it some time, but the links will be updated sooner or later.